# Selecting items from a list to achieve a sum

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, list, combinations

I have a list of items that has numeric values and I need to achieve a sum using these items. I need your help to build such an algorithm. Below, there is a sample that describes my problem, written in C#:

```
int sum = 21;

List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(new Item() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = 3 });
list.Add(new Item() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = 5 });
list.Add(new Item() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = 12 });
list.Add(new Item() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = 3 });
list.Add(new Item() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = 2 });
list.Add(new Item() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = 7 });

List<Item> result = // the items in the list that has the defined sum.
```

Note: I have no constraint on the number of items in the result.

Comment: This is NP-Complete: It's called the Subset-sum problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem . You're not going to find any *easy* solutions, unfortunately - the best solution found to date runs in `O(2 ^ (N/2))`.

Comment: Does the values needs to be the largest from available ?

Comment: Is homework tag missing?

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa. No it is not really a homework, cuz I am not a student :) I have a total amount of rebate and list of orders. I need to check orders automaticly on the user interface to get the sum.

Comment: @Vash. I actually dont have any constraint.

Comment: It's a recursive mess, which if done using Lists, can lead to serious memory consumption if a lot of numbers are given. This would be a more suitable problem for C. If you need it for actual use, I seriously don't advise the use of OOP, but rather simple C++ code with single direction linked lists.

Comment: Can you use particular item several times to construct the sum? This fact has a big influence on the solution complexity.

Comment: @Alexander. It is one of the things that I am trying to do in my ASP.NET project, so, I will probably not going to use other languages for this time, but thanks for your advice.

Comment: @MAKKAM I should not have same item in several times in my result.

Comment: I suppose it's better then to use dynamic programming approach described on the wikipedia page. Especially for small values of sum it's possible to construct O(sum*N*N) solution where N = list.Count;

Comment: @Musa Hafalir, I think that You not aware of some constraints, if You really don't have any then we look for x % item[i] == 0 and then add this item till we have that sum (x). So i think that You can use only once each value and this is a constraint. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called the **[Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)** and is considered a hard problem in computer science. Not hard as in hard to do, but hard to do *fast* — you can easily write an algorithm to do it, but for sizable inputs it will easily take billions of years.

If you are happy with a slow solution that is only practicable for small inputs, try something like this:

- Generate all subsets of the input list.
- For each subset, calculate the sum of the items in that subset.
- Return the first subset for which the sum matches.

Here is a method that returns all subsets (actually *subsequences* because it maintains the order of items, although in your case this makes no difference):

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns all subsequences of the input <see cref="IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source">The sequence of items to generate
/// subsequences of.</param>
/// <returns>A collection containing all subsequences of the input
/// <see cref="IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;"/>.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsequences<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    // Ensure that the source IEnumerable is evaluated only once
    return subsequences(source.ToArray());
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> subsequences<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source.Any())
    {
        foreach (var comb in subsequences(source.Skip(1)))
        {
            yield return comb;
            yield return source.Take(1).Concat(comb);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

So you can now write something like this...

```
var result = list.Subsequences()
                 .FirstOrDefault(ss => ss.Sum(item => item.Value) == sum);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be faster in most cases if you calculate a subset that approaches the sum you need to have and than look if there are any 1/2/3 elements that would just fit the margin you still need? Supposed you have a large set of numbers and an idea of how big the numbers are? I am asking this purely out of interest :)

Comment: May be we should first remove elements that has value greater than the sum :) I will still need some optimizations but the answer was very explanatory. Thanks.

Comment: @Samuel, @Musa: You have both come up with a possible optimisation. A few more and you might be on your way to computer science research! If you can prove your new algorithm to have a better complexity than O(2^(n/2)) and publish that proof in a peer-reviewed paper, you’ll be famous :)

Answer (score 2):

That's called the subset sum problem, with the modification - that you don't want to get to zero, but to a specific number.

Here's what Wiki has to say about it - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem.

You may think of some optimizations according to your knowledge of the domain. For example if the highest number + the lowest number are greater than the sum -> the highest number will never be used, and you can rule it out (and try the same for the new highest number..).

I remember doing it as Samuel suggested - the recursive way, which wasn't that terrible, (but of course there's always the stackoverflow issue...).

Answer (score 1):

recursive, add elements until A) you achieve the sum or B) you get too much, if A you're done, if B you change the elements trying all possible configurations. Maybe prohibit the system to add an element if the current element is already bigger than the last element that went over the sum

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure which sun you are after here. If you want the sum of all values combines, use this code:

```
int result = list.Sum( i => i.Value);
```

If you want all elements that has a specific value, use this code:

```
int x = 3;
List<Item> result = list.Where( i => i.Value == x);
```

Comment: should be `list.Where( i => i.Value == x);` (double equal sign for equality)

Comment: @Benny Jobigan  But that's not what the questioner even wants anyway

Comment: Sorry for the mispelling here. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @colithium Yea, I see now that the solution is something different. It was hard to understand what the OP wanted. Anyway, I was just pointing out a typo in the code (even though I doubt that would have compiled).