# How to make equal subsets of integers?

Tags: c#, linq, permutation, combinations

Suppose I have an array as under

```
array[] = {14,10,20,4}
```

This array can be divided into to subsets {14,10} and {20,4} since these two have equal sum.

Another example may be

```
array[] = {5, 5, 15, 5}
```

This array can be divided into to subsets {5,5,5} and {15} since these two have equal sum.

But

```
array[] = {1, 5, 30}
```

Cannot be divided into equal sets as they can never be equal.

How can we do so?

My shot

```
var result = string.Empty;
int highestNumber = input1[0];
int sum = 0;
string set = string.Empty;

foreach (int value in input1) 
    if (value > highestNumber) highestNumber = value;

for (int i = 0; i < input1.Length; i++)
{
    var elements = input1[i];
    if (elements > 0)
    {
        if (elements != highestNumber)
        {
            sum += elements;
            set += "," + elements; 
        }
    }
}

if (sum == highestNumber)
    result = "Yes it can be partitioned" 
else
    result = "No it cannot be";

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

It does not work for the first one.

How to do this program?

Comment: Does the result always have to be two subsets with equal value? Or is it allowed to have three subsets with equal value?

Comment: Do you have only to check if they are split-able into subsets or do you have to create the subsets as well? (The code implies the first assumption, the question the later.)

Comment: @Martin Mulder , It can even be odd e.g. {10,20,30} where {10,20} and {30} are equal

Comment: @priyanka: You do not understand my question. Could there be THREE resuling groups or do there alays have to be TWO? Example: {10,20,30,5,25} could result into: {10,20} + {5,25} + {30}.

Comment: @Martin Mulder ,it will always be two

Comment: @Priyanka: Are there any other criteria? Are negative numbers allowed? Or zero's? Are you looking for great performance or just functionality?

Comment: @Priyanka: What about if there are more combinations? Do you simply want only two groups or all possibilities to split into two groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to partition the given int array into 2 partitions where the sums of the partitions are equal.

The approach could be:

1. See if the sum of all items is divisible by 2 (otherwise, cannot be partitioned)
2. Get all subsets of the array
3. Find the subsets where the sum is [sum of all items] / 2

Here's the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arrays = new int[][] {
            new[]{ 1, 12, 10, 2, 23 },
            new[] {14,10,20,4},
            new[] {5, 5, 15, 5},
            new[] {1, 5, 30}
        };

        foreach (var array in arrays)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Results for {0}:", string.Join(",", array)));
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> partitions = Partition(array);
            if (!partitions.Any()) 
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot be partitioned.");
            else
                foreach (var item in partitions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", item));
                }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Partition(int[] array)
    {
        var sum = array.Sum();
        if ((sum % 2) == 1) return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<int>>();

        return Subsequences(array).Where(ss => ss.Sum(item => item) == (sum / 2));
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/3750709/201088
    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsequences<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source.Any())
        {
            foreach (var comb in Subsequences(source.Skip(1)))
            {
                yield return comb;
                yield return source.Take(1).Concat(comb);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Results for 1,12,10,2,23:
12,10,2
1,23

Results for 14,10,20,4:
14,10
20,4

Results for 5,5,15,5:
15
5,5,5

Results for 1,5,30:
Cannot be partitioned.
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution based on a array of bits, a bitset, in C# `bool[]`. Before I show the solution I first had to add some extension methods to this `bool[]`. These are generic functions and can be used in other solution. It is placed at the bottom of this answer.

As I said it is based on the bitset. The bitset will have the length of the array of numbers which need to be group. The bitset will be filled with zero's and one. Each bit corresponds with one number. So if the array of numbers has 5 elements, the bitset will also have 5 bits.

If a bit is `0`, the number is going to be place in `group0`. If the bit is `1`, the number is going to be placed into `group1`. When both groups have the same sum, the work is done.

This loop is repeated until all combinates are analyzed. The bitset will start with the numeric value op 1 (in case of 5 numbers: `00001`). It will increase every iteration (so the next interation will be `00010`, then `00011`, then `00100`, etc.) So changing the bits of the bitset and regrouping the numbers.

**Be aware:** I create this method with only its functionallity in mind. I did not mind any performance issues. Of course this routine can be made faster (i.e. not create new lists every iterations, etc.) but that would make the code less readable. I tried to make this code **as readable as possible**.

```
static public bool Partition(IList<int> numbers, out IList<int> group0, out IList<int> group1)
{
    if (numbers == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("numbers");

    bool[] groupPerNumber = new bool[](numbers.Count);
    while (true)
    {
        groupPerNumber.Increase(); // Increate the numberic value of the array of bits.
        if (groupPerNumber.IsEmpty()) // If all bits are zero, all iterations have been done.
            break;

        // Create the new groups.
        group0 = new List<int>();
        group1 = new List<int>();

        // Fill the groups. The bit in the groups-array determains in which group a number will be place.
        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Count; index++)
        {
            int number = numbers[index];
            if (!groupPerNumber[index])
                group0.Add(number);
            else
                group1.Add(number);
        }

        // If both sums are equal, exit.
        if (group0.Sum() == group1.Sum())
            return true;
    }
    group0 = group1 = null;
    return false;
}
```

**Array of boolean Extensions**

```
static public class BoolArrayExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Treats the bits as a number (like Int32) and increases it with one.
    /// </summary>
    static public void Increase(this bool[] bits)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!bits[i])
            {
                bits[i] = true;
                bits.SetAll(0, i - 1, false);
                return;
            }
            bits[i] = false;
        }
        bits.SetAll(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the subset of bits from the start position till length with the given value.
    /// </summary>
    static public void SetAll(this bool[] bits, int start, int length, bool value)
    {
        while(length-- > 0)
            bits[start++] = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if all bits in the collection are false.
    /// </summary>
    static public bool IsEmpty(this bool[] bits)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
            if (bits[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I created another solution like this and placed it at codereview. It is basically the same function, but this time optimized form speed. Interested? Take a look: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25980/performance-devide-group-of-numbers-into-two-groups-of-which-the-sums-are-equal

Comment: It seems like you're going through all possible combinations, from 00000 to 11111; this is not necessary. You only need to consider those masks where the number of "1" is <= N/2 Otherwise, you will analyse each combination twice. Also, you dont need to construct two groups and compare their sum. Its sufficient to check the sum of the smaller set, and compare it to: (the sum of the original array) / 2, which can be calculated in advance.

Comment: @Andy: That is entierly true. It is not the most efficient way. And I could sort it all, and create much more efficient routines. But he did not ask for efficiency. I asked for a method. And that why I created a simple method to understand. If focused on readability and understandability without any optimazations.

Comment: @Andy: I compared the speed of my solution (as inefficient as it is) and the solution of Eren: My solution is +/- 5 times faster. And with a few modification I can get a factor op 10.

Comment: I place my code at codereview.stackexchange.com, to get it reviewed and get suggestions for performance. If someone is interested and has suggestions, please respond at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25980/performance-devide-group-of-numbers-into-two-groups-of-which-the-sums-are-equal

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the sum of your array and divide it by two. Now you know the desired norm (summed value) of your sets.

Depending on your performance requirements and the expected size you can use a simple backtracking algorythm to walk down all possibilities. Since you know the exact sum which a set must have, you can limit the search significantly.

Answer (score -1):

First you can start out with a method to get the combinations for the items in a list.  This is most easily solved by creating the combinations for a number and then translating that from numbers to indexes of your collection:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IList<T> source, int n)
{
    return Combinations(source.Count, n)
        .Select(combination => combination.Select(i => source[i]));
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Combinations(int n, int p)
{
    //this is logically treated as a stack except that when enumerated it's enumerated as the 
    //reverse of a stack, which is desirable.  There is no efficient way to get the reverse iterator
    //of System.Collections.Stack so easily.  All mutations are to the end of the list.
    var stack = Enumerable.Range(0, p).ToList();

    while (stack[stack.Count - 1] < n)
    {
        //the ToList can be removed if previous sub-sequences won't be iterated 
        //after the outer sequence moves to the next item.
        yield return stack.ToList();
        int lastValue = stack.Pop();

        while (stack.Any() && lastValue + 1 > n - (p - stack.Count))
        {
            lastValue = stack.Pop();
        }

        while (stack.Count < p)
        {
            lastValue += 1;
            stack.Add(lastValue);
        }
    }
}

//simple helper method to get & remove last item from a list
public static T Pop<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    T output = list[list.Count - 1];
    list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
    return output;
}
```

Using that it's a simple matter to create a method to get all combinations for a set, rather than just combinations of a particular size:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> output = Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();
    for (int i = 1; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        output = output.Concat(Combinations(source, i));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Now that we have the ability to get all combinations for the list we can use LINQ to finish the job:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 5, 5, 15, 5 };

var groups = list.AllCombinations()
    .GroupBy(combination => combination.Sum());
```

Using that you now have all of the groups of combinations that sum up to the same value.

Comment: And how should the OP get the correct groups from your group-by collection? You are just halfway there!

Comment: @MartinMulder By definition *all* of the groups are the correct groups.  He's looking for the groups that all have the same sum.  There could be multiple collections of groups.  The OP doesn't specify which, if any, is correct, thus specifying all of them is correct.

Comment: The questions states that the array should be "equally" deviced in groups, where equally means that every group has the same sum. If you read the comments, you can read there are always TWO resulting groups, not more. If I put {14,10,20,4} in your code, it will result in 11 groups, while the exampel of the OP clearly states that two results are expected. Perhapse the correct answer is inside your result, but how to get that result then?

Comment: @MartinMulder The OP didn't state that only groups of size two are valid, I read it as he's only ever passing in data that results in groups of size two.  Also note that this answer doesn't just generate a flat list of groups; it generates a sequence of groups.  Each item in the collection is a series of groups that all have the same sum.  For the example's he's provided there will only be one, unlike your example, which has several collections of groups, each with a different sum.  As the OP never specified a means of determining which collection he wants, I provided all of them.

Comment: @MartinMulder If the OP only wants the groups with the largest sum, or the largest group of items with the same sum, etc. he can either filter the query I have provided, or add that additional constraint to the OP and I'll edit my answer accordingly.  As it is though; this answer meets the exact criteria specified in the question.

Comment: You said "The OP didn't state that only groups of size two are valid". Correct. Nobody says so. But the OP did state that the result should only exists of TWO collections with *n* elements. Agreed, you provide much more. But that much more is IMO an overkill to what is asked: just two collections. If this was about a userinterface which was filled with all your collections combined with the words "Now the user can find the correct collections for himself! The answer is in there!", would you consider that a good program? I think not. Now the OP asked you to produce TWO collections......

Comment: @MartinMulder No, the OP didn't specify that only groups of size two are valid, he said he'd only be passing data that resulted in groups of size two.  That's *completely different*.  It means that you can write more specialized code that is potentially either easier to write and/or more efficient based on knowing that the data being passed is more limited.  That doesn't make the more general program *wrong*.  If the OP said that it should only return collections of size two, rather than of any size, then that would make my program incorrect (but easily adjusted).

Comment: @Servery: I asked him: "You do not understand my question. Could there be THREE resuling groups or do there always have to be TWO? Example: {10,20,30,5,25} could result into: {10,20} + {5,25} + {30}.". OP replied: "It will always be two".

Comment: @MartinMulder Yes, and I read that as the data provided will be such that there will never be more than two groupings of items that share the same sum of values, not that he only wants two groups of values (even though there are more) of a particular sum.  If he said, "I only want to" rather than "there will always be two" then it would be a constraint he's assuming the program adds, not the data.

Comment: Then what was wrong with my example "{10,20,30,5,25}" which could result in 3 collection. Why did he not say: "Well, in your case there are three!" He responded with "Nope, always two!".

Comment: @MartinMulder I read that as saying that your example is invalid input for this function; it doesn't represent possible data that he will have.  As I've said many times, of the OP feels otherwise it's rather trivial to filter the data I've provide.  `.Where(group => group.Count() == 2)` is all it would take, if that's what he really wants, but I simply don't see that constraint in the question.  Your code on the other hand cannot be so trivially adapted if your interpretation of the question is incorrect.

Comment: Well... lets hope the OP will return to give the the answer to our debate.